# How to move along 2 axis EQUALLY?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

All I seem to be able to find when I search is the ability to lock an axis and move on the other 2 freely but I want to move along those 2 axis equally, so if I lock the Y and I move on the X and Z I want it to move the same distance on both the X and Z axis.

Picture: [image]

So as you can likely guess, I want to duplicate the nut and move it on an axis of 45°.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Blender can do this directly. You could rotate the nut 45 degrees, switch Blender to local coordinates, and then move along one of those axes.

Comment: Is there a way to make the local coordinates also work when pressing G? I don't want to move them all manually (clicking and dragging on the new local axis arrow on my selection) but rather define specific values to the axis I'm moving on.

Comment: Yes, press G and then X twice to move along the local X-axis.